# Error "The operator == is undefined for the argument type(s) char, boolean"

Tags: java

I'm trying to do this:

```
System.out.println("Do you want to solve an equation (y/n)?");
char first = In.getChar();
boolean y = true;
boolean n = false;

if(first == y)
  System.out.println("Enter a:");

if(first == n)
  System.out.println("Thanks");
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is that if I ask the user to solve the equation and the user presses <kbd>y</kbd> (meaning yes), then it will go through the `if` statement for which `y` is `true`; but if the user enters <kbd>n</kbd> (meaning no), then it will say something like "thanks for using the system".

I'm getting the error "The operator == is undefined for the argument type(s) char, boolean".

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

`y` is a `boolean`. `'y'` is a `char`

```
if (first == 'y') {
  ...
}
```

Comment: do you need those curly brackets?

Comment: its good practice so you can clearly see the scope of the `if` statment block otherwise only the first statement is used in the block :)

Answer (score 3):

You're comparing the different data types `char` and `boolean` and Java doesn't know how to do that. For example, what should be the result of this?

```
'a' == false
```

If you want to compare the content of a `char` variable with a specific `char` then do the following:

```
char charVar = 'n';
if (charVar == 'y') { // this would return "false", because 'n' is not equal 'y'
    //...
}
```

So you can change your code as follows:

```
if(first == 'y')
    System.out.println("Enter a:");
else if(first == 'n') // use "else if" instead of "if" :)
    System.out.println("Thanks");
```